# Why Как твои дела? Твои is for a plural subject

Tags: глаголы

Why are we saying Как твои дела? Твои is for plural subjects according to my notes. We say Твои книги.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is plural. Exactly like in "How are things?"

Comment: дела is singular

Comment: @Johan What would singular "дела" mean?

Comment: @Johan дела is most certainly not singular.

Comment: "дела́" is plural, nominative case - it is used in phrase "как твои дела?";
"де́ла" is singular, genitive case.

Comment: @MrZak: How are things? is actually more popular as a greeting than How are things going?

Comment: @CocoPop yes, probably. I was surpised a bit it is used in that way.

Answer (score 5):

The plural word **дела́**  *things* *is* the subject here. Think of it as **your things are how**, except inverted for a question.

The noun **де́ло** belongs to a class of nouns that are stressed on the stem in the singular (де́ло, де́ла, де́лом, де́ле, etc.) and stressed on the ending in the plural  forms (дела́, дела́м, дела́ми, дела́х, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The possible misunderstanding arose because the word "дела" may serve as [different parts of speech](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0) and hence will have different meanings depending on context.

1. дела́ (e.g. как [твои] дела́ ?)

   This is a general question, like "How are you?" in English and may be asked to inquire about one's disposition, health, business etc. In this case "дела́" is substantive, nominative case. It is in the plural because the question is general and not focusing on any concrete things.
   The original form of the question is ["как дела ?"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0):

   > *Приветствие, вопрос о текущем состоянии дел:*
   >   Это был грек из России, [...]. Одет он был бедно, выглядел печально. ― Как **дела́** ? ― спросил я у него. Он немного подумал и таинственно вздохнул: ― У вас хоть керосин есть.
   >   *Ф. А. Искандер, "Курортная идиллия"*

   Question "Как твое де́ло?" may be asked only regarding concrete business, when you would like to learn how is it going.
2. де́ла (куда ты его де́ла ?)

   In this case "де́ла" is a verb ["деть"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) in past time, gender feminine (it depends on "ты" and question assumes that your conversation partner ("ты") is of gender feminine).

   > 1. *разг. положить, запрятать так, что не найти*.
   >      На зов явилась женщина с тарелкой в руках [...]. И между ними произошел такой разговор: — Куда ты **де́ла**, разбойница, бумагу? — Ей-Богу, барин, не видывала, опричь небольшого лоскутка, которым изволили прикрыть рюмку.
   >      *Н.В.Гоголь, "Мертвые души"*.
   > 2. *разг. найти для кого-либо, чего-либо место или применение; поместить или использовать*.
3. де́ла (Без де́ла не входить)

   This is the substantive ["де́ло"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE) in genetive case, singular.

   > Много у вас **дела**? ― спросил Обломов. ― Да, довольно. Две статьи в газету каждую неделю, потом разборы беллетристов пишу, да вот написал рассказ...
   >   *И.А. Гончаров, "Обломов"*